# Create jquery dialog RactiveJS decorator

Tags: javascript, jquery, decorator, ractivejs

I would like to create a decorator for jQuery Dialog, in order to open and close a dialog by using data model.
This is the example code for template:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" decorator="jqueryDialog" show="{{dlgShow}}" twoway="true" modal="true" title="File already exists">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>File already exists, Do you want to overwrite it?</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var jqueryDialogDecorator = function ( node, content ) {

    var isModal = jQuery(node).attr('modal');

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            if (mutation.attributeName == 'show') {             
                var action = jQuery(node).attr('show') == 'true' ? 'open' : 'close';
                jQuery(node).dialog(action);
            }
        });    
    });

    observer.observe(node, {attributes: true});    

    jQuery(node).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: isModal,
        close: function( event, ui ) {
            jQuery(node).attr('show', 'false');         
        }
    }); 

    return {
        teardown: function () {

            observer.disconnect();

        }
    }

};

</script>
```

If I change dlgShow value to true, the dialog show correctly;
The callback on close function of the dialog change the **show attribute** value to *false*.
The problem is the ractive data **dlgShow** doesn't update despite the twoway binding, so the value is still set to true.
 Furthermore, I don't know how to programmatically get the binding name, i.e '*dlgShow*'.

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you !

Comment: Errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a mutation observer, you can use data binding with the decorator itself – you just need to return an `update` method along with the `teardown` method:

```html
<div id="dialog-confirm" decorator="jqueryDialog:{{dlgShow}}" modal="true" title="File already exists">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>File already exists, Do you want to overwrite it?</p>
</div>
```

[See example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/Ludjzdqe/).

(Incidentally, it turns out that this is [broken](http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/4atfc8k8/) in the development version of Ractive – have [raised an issue](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/2213).)

Comment: Thank for the answer: hovever, I need to manually set **content** to _false_ on the close event of the dialog, so I miss the code for do that